# In App and UITableView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, in-app-purchase

here is my code:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (isPurchased == NO) {

        return [UITableviewExample count];
        [UITableviewExample release];
    }
    else
    {
        return [UITableviewExample2 count];
        [UITableviewExample2 release];
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (isPurchased == NO) {

            cell.textLabel.text = [UITableviewExample objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            [UITableviewExample release];
        }
        else {
            cell.textLabel.text = [UITableviewExample2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            [UITableviewExample2 release];

        }
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Who can help me please? After successful in-app purchase, no changes. If I use

```
-(IBAction)test
{
    if (isPurchased == yes) {
        buyButton.hidden = yes;
    }
}
```

Works great. I tried for two apps, in-app purchase, everything works great, even if I use to hide, change text for label, it work, how can i make to work in-app purchase for UITableView? I want to change rows after successful in-app purchase. WHERE IS MY ERROR? Thank you.

Comment: Not to be rude, but your code is very difficult to understand what you are doing. What are these `UITableViewExample` objects, and why are you releasing them everywhere? You really should read and take to heart Apple's Objective-C style guide and memory management guides. It will help you write more standardized code and help others understand it quicker. Also, your text explanation is unclear, and you provide no info on what's happening with the in-app purchase itself. For these reasons I have to downvote your question.

Comment: Also, read the tag wiki for Xcode. This question isn't in any way related to Xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the very least, a couple of obvious edits to `numberOfRowsInSection` (where the code never reaches the `release` statements, but you wouldn't want it to, anyway) and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` (where you are performing inappropriate `release` statements and there is a logic bug if the cell was ever successfully dequeued):

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (isPurchased == NO) {
        return [UITableviewExample count];
        // [UITableviewExample release];
    }
    else
    {
        return [UITableviewExample2 count];
        // [UITableviewExample2 release];
    }

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // this was in the above "if (cell == nil)" block, but should be outside of it

    if (isPurchased == NO) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [UITableviewExample objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        // [UITableviewExample release];
    }
    else {
        cell.textLabel.text = [UITableviewExample2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        // [UITableviewExample2 release];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Stylistically, you also apparently have variables `UITableviewExample` and `UITableviewExample2`, but as a matter of good programming style, variable names should start with a lowercase letter, e.g. `tableviewExample` and `tableviewExample2`.

To the substance of your question, you need to show us how these `NSArray` (or `NSMutableArray`) objects are getting initialized. The problem may not rest in the above code, but rather in the population of those arrays.

But to the excellent observation by Guntis, if your problem is that you are not seeing the table change after the in app purchase, you may need to perform a `reloadData`.

Answer (score 1):

try calling reloadData for tableView - when you receive notification, that in-App purchase has been done.

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

or with animations:

```
[tableView reloadSections:0 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```